# Populate html textbox with Javascript canvas data

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I currently have a canvas with a couple of images in it, I use the following code to get the width and height of the image when I click on the image:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    var mx = mouse.x;
    var my = mouse.y;
    var shapes = myState.shapes;
    var l = shapes.length;
    for (var i = l-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (shapes[i].contains(mx, my)) {
        var mySel = shapes[i];
        myState.selection = mySel;
        myState.valid = false;
            var message = 'Image width*height = ' + mySel.w + '*' + mySel.h;
    alert(message);
        return;
      }
    }
```

And I have some simple HTML text boxes like this:

```
Width:<input type="text" id="width" size="10">
Height:<input type="text" id="height" size="10">
```

Is it possible to somehow populate the textboxes with the width and height when I click on the image? Is there maybe a way I could put the width and height to a php variable and put that value in the textbox? I haven't got much experience with Javascript so I don't know if this is possible or not.

If someone could push me in the right direction or maybe provide an example or a usefull link it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the click event does get the width and height of an image it would be as simple as adding this:

```
document.getElementById('width').value = mySel.w;
document.getElementById('height').value = mySel.h;
```

Comment: No problems, glad to help